# How can I realize "protocol mediation" in a WSO2 ESB project?

Tags: wso2, protocols, amqp, mqtt, wso2-esb

I am studying how to realize a real "protocol mediation" using a WSO2 ESB used for collecting several messages in different protocols (http, amqp, mqtt...) and data format.

How can I use ESB features (mediators, for example) in order to realize a real synergy among several different protocols? Do I need some other modules of WSO2 or the ESB can make it on his own?

I hope my first question is clear.

Edit: i would need to treat XML files, exactly SDMX files. Can I transport them mediating an SDMX message in a simple XML message? Thx.

Answer (score 0):

For the protocol mediation,(ie: protocol switching) you can try out Proxy services, which receive message from one protocol and sending to another service endpoint which runs on another protocol. When the message pass through the system, you can use mediators to modify the messages.

You can follow the [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/ESB481/Transports+Samples+and+Switching+Transports) for further information